# Classification of complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

**Is there anything known about classification of complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ up to isomorphism for $n>1$? Say, are there finitely or infinitely many isomorphism classes? If there is a reasonable moduli space, is it finite or infinite dimensional?**

Remark. For $n=1$ there exist exactly two complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^2$: one is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, the other one to the unit disc. This is a special case of the uniformization theorem saying that any simply connected complex 1-dimensional manifold is isomorphic either to unit disk, or to $\mathbb{C}$, or to $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: This paper of Hjorth and Kechris may be of interest: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255984956. It deals with using descriptive set theory to understand the classification problem for arbitrary Riemann surfaces (not just structures on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$), and shows that even in complex dimension $1$, this is extremely complicated (the "moduli space" is "Borel equivalent" to the quotient of $\{0,1\}^{F_2}$ by the left shift action of the free group $F_2$). For higher dimensions, it is more complicated ("not classifiable by countable structure" in the subject's parlance).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There exist *infinitely many* inequivalent complex structures in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

See for instance the paper

K. Diederich, N. Sibony: *[Strange complex structures on Euclidean space](https://eudml.org/doc/152188)*, Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik **311-312**, page 397-407 (1979)

and the references given therein.

Answer (score 8):

There are even infinitely many inequivalent complex structures without non-constant holomorphic functions on $\Bbb R^4$ [download](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06097).